# Coil: display a new image that has the same name and path as the previous image

Tags: android, image, coil

In my app, the user selects an image from the gallery by clicking a button. After that, he can select another image from the gallery by pressing the button again, and the new image will replace the previous one. But the point is that the selected image is first saved with the same name as the previous image and then displayed. The problem is that `Asyncimage()` does not show the new item because the new and previous items have the same name (and path). How can I force `Asyncimage()` to look at the same path again?

I tried `CachePolicy.DISABLED` and it didn't work:

```
AsyncImage(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data(uiState.value.imagePath)
        .crossfade(true)
        .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
        .build(),
...
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable `diskCachePolicy`.

```
...
.diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
...
```

Furthermore, you can remove disk cache manually before set the data to AsyncImage.

```
context.imageLoader.diskCache?.remove(uiState.value.imagePath)
```

Comment: @AleksiSinelnikov, Thank you for the answer. No, none of these two methods worked. I finally decided to use different names.

Comment: Well, be sure that your compose function recomposes

Comment: @AleksiSinelnikov, I made a special variable in the uiState to ensure recomposition, and the result: No. It still doesn't work.